# Ruby XML Builder, how to create this namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-builder

I'm using Ruby's XML Builder and trying to find the proper syntax to recreate the following RSS 2.0 declaration:

```
<rss version="2.0" 
xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
```

What's the appropriate way of going about this with XML Builder to put together the above block?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this builder script:

```
xml.rss :version => "2.0", "xmlns:g" => "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" do
end
```

This will yield:

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
</rss>
```

Comment: The above method works perfectly. Another option is to use:-
xml.rss "version" => "2.0", "xmlns:g" => "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" do
end
for uniformity.